# How do I cancel my Google Play Music subscription?

Tags: google-play-music

I signed up for a trial of Google Play Music but didn't cancel it before the trial period expired. Now it's taking £9.99 from my card every month. How can I make it stop?

Comment: As Izzy says, this is a Q&A site for fellow Android users to help each other out. We're not Google, we're not taking your money, and we can't fix it for you, but we **can** help you know what to do to fix it. I've edited your question to make it something we can answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Play support website](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3122088?hl=en-GB) explains how to cancel the Google Play Music subscription. From your Android device, you do it from inside the settings screen of the Play Music app. Or on a desktop computer or iPhone, you can cancel it through the [Google Play Music website](https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=0#/settings).

The first site I linked also has a "live chat" feature. If you need someone to walk you through it step-by-step, you can talk to a Google support person that way.